# short url for joomla k2 extension

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

Joomla 3.2/k2 2.6.5

I use this code to make seo url for k2 items link.

```
$item->link = urldecode(JRoute::_(K2HelperRoute::getItemRoute($item->id.':'.urlencode($item->alias), $item->catid.':'.urlencode($item->categoryalias))));
```

and It gives me an Url path like this:

**MYSITE.COM/CAT/SUBCAT/SUB2cat/ITEM.HTML**

Is there any way to convert it to one of these addresses?

**MYSITE.COM/ITEM.HTML**

**MYSITE.COM/CAT/ITEM.HTML**

**MYSITE.COM/SUB2CAT/ITEM.HTML**

Comment: You can use K2 advanced SEO features or you can use an extension like SH404SEF.

Comment: I knew,I want to do it myself.